# What does the android reference mean by this?

Tags: android

> ```
> protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
> ```
>
> > Added in API level 1 This method is called after onStart() when the
> >     activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given
> >     here in savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
> >     onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
> >     convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
> >     or **to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
> >     implementation**. The default implementation of this method performs a
> >     restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
> >     onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
> >
> > This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Not able to understand the bold part.

Comment: Reason for the downvote(s)? Sorry if it violates any terms of stackoverflow. I could not understand that, I was not able to ask it in a "coding question" way and I had nowhere else to go for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, when a class subclasses another class, it has the option of overriding public and protected methods from the superclass.  There is no obligation to do this, but if there is an override, the overridden method can choose to call back into the superclass's implementation of the method.  The call to the superclass is not a default behavior, it is a decision that the implementer of the subclass has to make.

This javadoc is just making it clear that subclasses that override this method may need to carefully consider if they want to call back into the superclass for the purpose of performing addition optional restoration of saved state.

Comment: Why is the same thing not written for the onCreate(Bundle) which is also a protected method and thus can be overridden. It also receives the same bundle that the onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) is receiving. Since they are talking about the difference between the two methods, what exactly is the difference other than convenience?

Comment: Because it clearly states why we may use this method to get the saved state instead of doing this in onCreate(Bundle):
1: It is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done.
2: To allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation.
How is the number 2 not possible in onCreate(Bundle)?

Comment: The same thing is not written for onCreate because you HAVE to call through to the superclass in onCreate.  This method is your chance to optionally call to the superclass to allow it to also restore the state from onRestoreInstanceState. The subclass may decide in some cases not to allow the super to what it normally does there.  This is an edge case and not frequently required.  If you don't know that you need it, then don't use it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :)